# Cómo saber el índice de posiciones de una matriz de PHP

Tags: php

Tengo estas matrices:

```
$carsPedro = array (
    array("Volvo",1,13000),
    array("BMW",3,13500),
    array("Saab",2,12000),
    array("Land Rover",4,15000)
  );

$carsMaria = array (
    array("Volvo",1,13000),
    array("BMW",2,13500),
    array("Saab",2,14000),
    array("Land Rover",4,15000)
  );
```

y quiero sacar los índices de las posiciones dónde hay valores distintos en las matrices. Es decir, actualmente he intentado dos códigos:

```
$changes=array();

  for ($a=0; $a < count($carsPedro); $a++) { 
    for ($b=0; $b < count($carsPedro[$a]) ; $b++) { 
        if($carsPedro[$a][$b] !== $carsMaria[$a][$b]){
            array_push($changes, key($carsPedro[$a][$b]));
        }
    }
}
```

Me da error porque me dice que key() expects parameter 1 to be array, integer given. No sé cómo hacerlo. He probado otra alternativa

```
$changes=array();

  for ($a=0; $a < count($carsPedro); $a++) { 
    for ($b=0; $b < count($carsPedro[$a]) ; $b++) { 
        if($carsPedro[$a][$b] !== $carsMaria[$a][$b]){
            array_push($changes, $carsPedro[$a][$b]);
        }
    }
}
```

pero esta me devuelve los valores que no coinciden, no los índices de los mismos. Sé que tiene que ser algo con key(), pero no he sido capaz de averiguar en qué estoy fallando.
Estoy probando con otra posible solución.

```
$changes=array();

  for ($a=0; $a < count($carsPedro); $a++) { 
    for ($b=0; $b < count($carsPedro[$a]) ; $b++) { 
        if($carsPedro[$a][$b] !== $carsMaria[$a][$b]){
            array_push($changes, $carsPedro[$a][$b]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($changes); //Tengo un array con los valores que son distintos de la matriz de Pedro
echo "<br>";

$index=array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($changes) ; $i++) { //Recorro la matriz con los valores distintos de Pedro
    array_search($changes[$i], $carsPedro); //Busca los valores distintos en el array de carsPedro 
    array_push($index, $changes[$i]); 
}

var_dump($index);
```

Básicamente con esa solución lo que quiero hacer es... Ok, tengo los valores que son distintos. Los busco dentro del array, le saco la posición y meto dichas posiciones en un array. No es lo óptimo, ya que este algoritmo se utilizará luego en una BBDD, y lo ideal es que te saque las posiciones de los valores que no son iguales directamente, no buscando luego por los valores que son distintos (ya que, por ejemplo, si un valor que es distinto es 2, puede haber varios 2 en la tabla).

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Esto no hace el trabajo: `foreach ($carsPedro as $k=>$subArray){ if (!in_array($subArray, $carsMaria)) { echo $k.PHP_EOL; } }`?

Comment: No, me devuelve 1, 2. Devuelve que hay dos posiciones distintas entiendo, pero no dice cuáles. Las posiciones dónde hay datos distintos (es decir, lo que quiero que me devuelva la función) son 1,1; 2, 2.

Comment: Claro, esas son las posiciones distintas, la `1` es el array de `BMW` y la `2` es el array de `Saab`, ten en cuenta que los índices de array empiezan por `0`.

Comment: Pero es una matriz, no un array. Que me diga que hay algo distinto en el array de BMW y que me diga que hay algo distinto en el array de Saab no me sirve. Necesito los índices exactos de las posiciones dónde los valores son distintos.